# Missing HttpContext

Tags: .net, httpcontext

I've got a project which as a reference added to System.Web.

However, it can't seem to pick up HttpContext. Doing this:

```
Imports System.Web
_ApplicationBase = HttpContext.Current()
```

Tells me that HttpContext is not declared. If you look at the methods and properties inside System.Web there are hardly any showing: only AspHostingPermission, AspHostingPermissionAttribute, AspHostingPermissionLevel and Services.

The reference is valid and pointing to the right place. This is driving me crazy - what have I missed?

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `HttpContext` object exists only during an asp.net request on the thread that is processing the request. In any other thread or process, there is no `HttpContext` available.

Comment: This is correct if the error happens at run-time.  If it happens at design time then you're missing a reference to the System.Web.dll assembly.

Answer (score 7):

If this error is happening at design time then it's a case of a missing assembly reference.  Make sure your project is referencing the System.Web.dll assembly.

Comment: Thanks, Work like charm after adding the reference.